# React state value is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I am building a music player app and I have a function that takes a value from an object in the state of the component.

When I give that value to the function it prints undefined and than the value itself, so the function cant work with an undefined value.

this is what the firstSong component looks like when Im printing the state:

```
{
    Title: "One Dance",
    Artist: "Drake",
    Length: "4:03",
    Path:
      "/home/songs/Drake - One Dance ft. EMØ.mp3"
  }
```

this is the full component code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import {
  faBackward,
  faPlay,
  faForward,
  faStop
} from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import styled from "styled-components";
import axios from "axios";

const CardStyling = styled.div`
  .card-body {
    width: 100%;
  }

  #song-header {
    margin-bottom: 25px;
  }

  #artist {
    margin-bottom: 25px;
  }

  #time {
    margin-bottom: 25px;
  }
`;

let display = "none";
const firstSongApi = "http://localhost:4001/getFirstSong";
const playSongApi = "http://localhost:4001/playSong";

export default class SongInfo extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      firstSong: this.getFirstSong(firstSongApi),
      isPlaying: false
    };
  }

  getFirstSong = async firstSongApi => {
    const request = await axios({
      method: "get",
      url: firstSongApi,
      headers: {}
    });
    try {
      let firstSong = request.data.firstSong;
      this.setState({
        firstSong: firstSong
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  playOrPauseSong = path => {
    console.log(path);
  };

  render() {
    {
      this.playOrPauseSong(this.state.firstSong.path);
    }
    return (
      <CardStyling className="card">
        <div className="card-body">
          <h3 id="song-header">{this.state.firstSong.Title}</h3>
          <h5 id="artist">By: {this.state.firstSong.Artist}</h5>
          <h5 id="Time">{this.state.firstSong.Length}</h5>
          <button type="button" id="back-btn" className="btn">
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBackward} />
          </button>
          <button
            type="button"
            id="play-btn"
            className="btn"
            onClick={() => this.playOrPauseSong(this.state.songLocation)}
          >
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlay} />
          </button>
          <button
            type="button"
            id="stop-btn"
            className="btn"
            style={{ display: display }}
          >
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faStop} />
          </button>
          <button type="button" id="next-btn" className="btn">
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faForward} />
          </button>
        </div>
      </CardStyling>
    );
  }
}
```

I would like the function to get the real path value and not undefined, thank you in advance!

Comment: could you share the full component

Comment: Give me context into what firstSong looks like in state, probably you did not create state in constructor or anywhere, also show the function where this.playOrPauseSong(song) is called

Comment: I have posted the full component code, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your state looks like the below and the path will log correctly inside playOrPauseSong;

```
    this.state = {
      firstSong: {
        title: "One Dance",
        artist: "Drake",
        length: "4:03",
        path:
          "/home/songs/Drake - One Dance ft. EMØ.mp3"
      }
    }


  playOrPauseSong = path => {
    console.log(path)
  }

  render(){

    return(
      <div>
        {this.playOrPauseSong(this.state.firstSong.path)}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Comment: Sorry but it didnt work, it prints me :   ./src/Components/SongInfo.js
Syntax error: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag. Did you want a JSX fragment <>...</>? (81:7)

  79 |         {this.playOrPauseSong(this.state.firstSong.path)}
  80 |       </div>
> 81 |       <CardStyling className="card">
     |       ^
  82 |         <div className="card-body">
  83 |           <h3 id="song-header">{this.state.firstSong.Title}</h3>
  84 |           <h5 id="artist">By: {this.state.firstSong.Artist}</h5>

Comment: @nadavatar it means you have to wrap your elements in a parent div or use fragment.

Answer (score 0):

```js
render() {
    {
      this.playOrPauseSong(this.state.firstSong.path);
    }
...
```

The reason it's undefined it's that your `firstSong` was still undergoing network request which is `async` method, and hence there wont be any `firstSong` nor `firstSong.path` and hence it's `undefined`. So instead you could update to following

```js
render() {
    {
      this.state.firstSong.path && this.playOrPauseSong(this.state.firstSong.path);
    }
```

So what it does is that, when there is no `path`, the method won't be invoked and it will be invoked when there's returned result from your network call, but really, you should introduce another flag to skip calling `this.playOrPauseSong` because your component will be keep re-rendering and you won't want to keep calling it everytime it re-renders

**UPDATES:**

Let's restructuring a lil bit

We can make the initial state of `firstSong` as `null` and we invoke the getFirstSong separately, so your constructor should be as below

```js
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    firstSong: null,
    isPlaying: false
  };
  this.getFirstSong(firstSongApi);
}
```

Then for your `render` method you gonna do checking on `firstSong` instead because on initial load, firstSong is gonna be null so update to the following

```js
render() {
    {
      this.state.firstSong && this.playOrPauseSong(this.state.firstSong.path);
    }
```

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer, but now when I call the function like you mentioned above the function doesnt even get called.

Comment: @nadavatar: That's unexpected, can you do a `console.log` within `getFirstSong` to make sure it's being invoked?

Comment: @nadavatar: Have a try on my updated section of code

Comment: It prints me the following error:                                                                     TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of null

Comment: @nadavatar: That's cuz we need to do checking on `this.state.firstSong` on `render` method

Comment: Can you please tell me what do you mean by checking on this.state.firstSong on render method, because I am checking if it has a vakue like you suggested in the updated comment

Comment: @nadavatar: The statement `this.state.firstSong && this.playOrPauseSong(this.state.firstSong.path)` itself is a checking on `this.state.firstSong` because if it's `null` which returns a falsey value, `this.playOrPauseSong` will not be executed. Point is, does it work as expected?

Comment: Well no, because I want the playOrPause song method to be executed when there is a path value...

Comment: @nadavatar: yeah, I totally get you and the code should be working, if it's not please state your problem, exception or? And it would be good if you can create a reproducible scenario @ codesandbox